# Is there any way to force firefox to a certain geometry without a window manager?

Tags: firefox, kiosk, xorg

I want to run Firefox directly on top of X for a kiosk, but I can't get it to maximize so there is blank space off to the right.

As far as I know, Firefox does not support the standard `--geometry` option; several attempts at this were fruitless.

There used to be a javascript hack that resized the window, but a new "feature" breaks that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a more suited window manager: matchbox. It automagically sets the window to the entire viewing field, and is very light-weight.

```
sudo apt-get install matchbox-window-manager
```

and in my kiosk session file:

```
while (true ) do
    matchbox-window-manager &
    firefox <my url here>
done;
```

Don't let their semi-unprofessional site turn you away--it works like a charm.

http://matchbox-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Would [Xnee](http://itupw056.itu.chalmers.se/project-xnee/) help? Record pressing F11 and it could work?

Comment: In kiosk mode, F11 does nothing.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. How about this? [XAutomation](http://xautomation.sourceforge.net/window.html) requires some python..

Comment: Oy, how about xdotool? http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/ from documentation scan looks like it's separate from window manager extensions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a library which overrides Firefox window positioning. Every time Firefox requests a specific position of the window, the call gets modified to include your specified position.

1. download and compile:

   ```
   wget http://www.ipsec.info/w/t/override-gtk-geometry.c
   gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o override-gtk-geometry.so `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` override-gtk-geometry.c
   ```
2. run:

   ```
   IPSEC_OVERRIDE_X=10 IPSEC_OVERRIDE_Y=10 \
   IPSEC_OVERRIDE_W=300 IPSEC_OVERRIDE_H=300 \
   LD_PRELOAD=./override-gtk-geometry.so firefox
   ```